# Set user agent for Node JS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-agent

Is it possible to configure the user-agent of a simple Node JS server? For example, I would like to run my node server using an iPhone user agent to simulate the device display. Not sure if there is an NPM package doing this or a custom javascript to manipulate the user-agent of a Node JS server.

Detail: I am aware about [express-user-agent](https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent)

It will only give your parsing feature and access to your current user-agent within your Express app.

Here is the code of my Node JS server:

```
 var express = require('express');
 var app = express();
 var server = require('http').createServer(app);
 var io = require('socket.io')(server);
 var exec = require('child_process').exec;
 var shell = require('shelljs');

 app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });

 server.listen(4200);

 io.on('connection', function(client) {
  client.on('join', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

 client.on('command', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Look this:

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
  url: 'http://localhost:4200/test',
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'MY IPHINE 7s'
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
          //do somethings
}

request(options, callback);
```

For example you can add test-route to your server and send get request. Dont forget about url to request, it must be http://localhost:4200/test, code:

```
...

 app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

 app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
 });

app.get('/test', function(req, res,next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
});


server.listen(4200);

...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, appreciate that. Do you know how I can check on my node js server that it is now using the custom user-agent-string?

Comment: I know that I can request URI like Facebook and see the mobile version but I am using an iFrame and cannot do that.